# Imagemagick error uploading image with refinery

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, refinerycms

Hi stackoverflow community,

I've a ruby project with refinery and using imagemagick to handle the images that I want to upload to my webpage. I don't know how describe the entire scenery because I'm very new with this. When I try to upload an image I get the following:

[image]

it says that I have to supply an api key. but I don't know where I can find it. Or how to solve it. I've Ubuntu 13.1 x64bits. I got ruby and imagemagick successfully installed.

the stack trace looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/duranmla/10937395)

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to read the stack trace...  That's the important part!  But if you're uploading to Cloudinary, it appears to be a service, and typically you'd need an API key for that.

Comment: Let me upload the stack trace, sorry about that.

Comment: @NickVeys I updated the post [This is the stack trace](https://gist.github.com/duranmla/10937395)

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding the following to my code:

[image]